# Can Oracle DB be used with Tornado?

Tags: oracle11g, tornado

I've only used Tornado with MySQL so far, but I need it to use data from an Oracle database. Is this easy to do?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/). From their website:

> SQLAlchemy includes dialects for SQLite, Postgresql, MySQL, **Oracle**,
>   MS-SQL, Firebird, Sybase and others, most of which support multiple
>   DBAPIs

Answer (score 1):

Since you program Tornado using python, any python tool is available for use.  You can see all the oracle related projects on pypi: http://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=oracle&submit=search

Be aware though, that unless you're using an asynchronous driver, all your database calls will be blocking, which means your individual Tornado server threads will all be stuck waiting for the backend.  I can't seem to find any async Oracle drivers, so good luck with that.

That said, the mysql driver (and tornado.database module provided by tornado) is synchronous.  The creators of tornado believe it's fine to use an async driver so long as you don't perform any slow queries.

Comment: Hello from the future. Actually, your point on async driver is very important. Looks like the workaround is to use [twisted](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/vasiliev-python-concurrency-087536.html) and [tornado bridge](http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/twisted.html)